# We have inherited a container shaped like a puppy. It is signed in cursive script...can anyone tell be by who? We think it is Japanese

Tags: translation

[image]

[image]
puppy container, possibly Japanese, signed

Comment: I‘m not an expert, and I'm not really sure (so I'm open to criticism). The bottom left is definitely 之 which is common in Japanese and Chinese. The one on top of 之 appears to be 生, which makes the most sense. But, I'm not entirely sure as it could also possibly be 岂 or 岜. My best guess overall is 粉秀(the right from top to bottom) 生之， so maybe it means produced/born from this woman 粉秀？

Comment: This first figure should come from China not Japan. The four  characters are chinese.